# How do use docker-compose to run commands between the docker image and the entrypoint?

Tags: docker, command, docker-compose, dockerfile

## docker compose v3

I'm trying to run some app-specific commands like `composer update` whenever I run `docker-compose up`, having my docker-compose.yml file look something along the lines of this

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: laraedit/laraedit 
    ports:
        - 3000:80
    volumes:
        - ./appfolder:/var/www/appfolder
```

If I run my first-run commands in the entrypoint, it will override all the commands that default laraedit/laraedit is running.  (At least I think so, because the container always stops when my entrypoint commands finish)

I don't want to bother the process of laraedit/laraedit starting up, I just want to execute a couple of commands on the side.

If I weren't using docker-compose, then I would have laraedit/laraedit Dockerfile locally, and I could then edit it and add a RUN statement somewhere in there.

But since I don't have the Dockerfile, and I can't make an entrypoint without throwing off the container's normal startup, I don't know how to go about automating the process of running these boring commands every single time I run `docker-compose up`.

Things I've tried:

- adding my own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dockerfile) (that replaces laraedit's)
- running an [entrypoint script](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) (that blocks laraedit's startup)
- running them as a [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) (the commands did not execute)

Comment: AFAIU, If you don't want to use "laraedit/laraedit" image then you have to edit it by using different Dockerfile. Create new image by the newly created Dockerfile & use it in your compose file. I am waiting for answers too :-) .

Comment: is this https://github.com/laraedit/laraedit-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile the original dockerfile? if so, when overriding the `command` or the `entrypoint` does `supervisord` is running?

Comment: @ItayB Yes, that is the right dockerfile.  When overriding the `command` or `entrypoint` values from `docker-compose.yml`, `supervisord` never runs.

Comment: U could do an ugly hack, starts supervisord in background (&), then run your stuff, then sleep 1 in while true.. make sense?

Comment: Makes sense yes. But too ugly of a hack for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the laraedit/laraedit image with a custom one.
You can use a Dockerfile as simple as this:

```
FROM laraedit/laraedit
COPY my_entrypoint.sh /my_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /my_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /my_entrypoint.sh
```

`my_entrypoint.sh` is a script that contains your initialization commands and calls the original entrypoint at its end, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_init_cmd1
my_init_cmd2

...

/original/entrypoint/script/path
```

You can get `/original/entrypoint/script/path` value by reading the original laraedit Dockerfile

Let's say you put the 2 files above in a directory called `docker` alongside your docker-compose.yml, than you need to adjust your docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    build: ./docker/
    ports:
    - 3000:80
    volumes:
    - ./appfolder:/var/www/appfolder
```